# Sources directory is already NetBeans project error

Tags: netbeans

i got that error and i can't add project in netbeans.. please teach me how to fix this

even if i rename my folder it doesn't work...

Comment: Without some more background information (what are you trying to achieve, your system, netbeans version...) it is hard to tell.

Comment: i'm trying to add a project in netbeans. but it is rejecting it.. i have added it before but i can't see it in my files section.. the version of the ide is 6.9.1

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Netbeans tries to add a folder (nbproject) to your project during import. If it is already there NB fails to add it. Move the existing nbproject folder to a different directory outside your project and try to import again.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089189/netbeans-doesnt-open-project-from-existing-sources).

Comment: i deleted the nbproject but it still not accepting my request to import the porject

Comment: anyhow i just check the option "put netbeans metadata into a separate directory".. i hope this won't break my code in the future.. thanks man

Comment: You have to restart Netbean once you deleted the folder.

Answer (score 20):

Delete the `nbproject` folder in your project directory and restart the IDE.

Comment: that restarting part made all the difference. that was important :)

Answer (score 7):

I had a PHP project with maven `pom.xml`, with no `nbproject` directory and clear cache, and netbeans would refuse to create a new project from sources with that `pom.xml` in place. Had to remove `pom.xml`, create a project and put `pom.xml` back.

Comment: presence of pom.xml tells netbeans that the folder is a project. Only workaround is to either delete/rename the pom.xml file or disable the maven support in the IDE.

Comment: if you have maven support installed, then it's a maven project. That's a consequence of having maven projects supported natively, without netbeans specific metadata.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem with:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/netbeans
rm ~/.netbeans/.superId
```

Comment: why would you do it the hard way? Can't you use the GUI?

Comment: Not in my case. In that occasion this was the only way I found.

Comment: a maven project does not create nb folder still refuses to load

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating it as a `New Project` try `Open Project` if `nbproject` directory exists in your project root directory.

Comment: I hade the same problem, ie I could not see one of my projects in the project pane. However, it was still there in File->Open Recent Project.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp: in `netbeans` if you close a project or move its code to some other directory then that project will be shown in `Open Recent Project`

Answer (score 0):

This happen to me on MS Windows as well.
Cause was netbeans.conf's

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Dline.separator=LF"
```