# Getting "Project folder ins managed by a project..." when opening Actviti source code in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ant, activiti

I can't open [Activiti source code](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti) in netbeans It just says "Project folder is managed by a project Activiti. Instead of creating a new project just open it. If by a chance you just deleted the project Activiti then restart the IDE to reuse the folder."

I have restarted Netbeans and re-cloned the project but it still won't open.

And eclipse just says that the javac was not found in the build.xml.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The project folder does not contain a nbproject folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you duplicating question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089189/netbeans-doesnt-open-project-from-existing-sources

Comment: Right but the folder containing my project does not have a nbproject folder or file.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- rename the `pom.xml` file to something else, e.g. `pom.xmlzzzz`,
- create the project in NetBeans,
- rename `pom.xmlzzzz` back to `pom.xml` once the project has loaded in NetBeans.

I've just hit the same problem with a different project and this is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans creates a folder in your project named "nbproject". Once you delete that, restart the IDE and you're good to go.

1. Go to the folder containing your project
2. Delete the folder named nbproject
3. Restart Netbeans
4. Try creating your project again from the original folder

Comment: Thanks but the folder does not contain a nbproject folder. Look at my edits to my post.

Comment: Try to create new project, restart NetBeans and open recently used projects